# Jquery detect which block is visible on screen when scroll

Tags: jquery, dynamic, scroll, visible

Hi all I have some questions, if it's not hard please help.

If i have some count of div blocks

```
<div class="main">
      <div class="box block1"></div>
      <div class="box block2"></div>
      <div class="box block3"></div>
      <div class="box block4"></div>
</div>
```

Ok now when you scroll and block visible on screen I need do something in that block I can do this with jquery every time when I scroll detect scroll top and check it with block offset-top but it bad solution because i need write many "if" to check it and it works when I have fixed count of block but i need that it will work dynamic. I find some plugins but I don't want use plugin. I was some basic easy script that i can change something or add or modify in other web sites

please help if you have some time to do that

it's my html

[example](https://jsfiddle.net/5ppdnbkj/)

I do something in my portfolio page but it not dynamic and I write bad code :)

you can see it on menu when you scroll i add active class to menu if visible the block

[portfolio](http://arammkrtchyan.info/)

Comment: Check this plugin https://github.com/morr/jquery.appear Might work for you

Comment: thank you but I know this plugin, I do many searches but it not that i want :)

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```js
function isVisible( row, container ){
    
    var elementTop = $(row).offset().top,
        elementHeight = $(row).height(),
        containerTop = container.scrollTop(),
        containerHeight = container.height();
    
    return ((((elementTop - containerTop) + elementHeight) > 0) && ((elementTop - containerTop) < containerHeight));
}
$(window).scroll(function(){
  $('.main div').each(function(){
      if(isVisible($(this), $(window))){
      console.log($(this).attr('class')+" is visible");
      };  
  });
});
```

```css
.main .box {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .main .block1 {
        background: red;
        height: 800px;
    }
    .main .block2 {
        background: green;
        height: 600px;
    }
    .main .block3 {
        background: yellow;
        height: 900px;
    }
    .main .block4 {
        background: orange;
        height: 1000px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
          <div class="box block1"></div>
          <div class="box block2"></div>
          <div class="box block3"></div>
          <div class="box block4"></div>
    </div>
```

On the console, You will note that only visible part of block elements is displayed!

And by default you get the part of displayed block by removing the scroll event.

Comment: ok this answer is better then previus. but now the problem is in that when you scrool and  first block an second block visible in the sc reen it says that the second block is visibl and also says that the first block visible  i want to it start write that second block visible when hide first block

Comment: @AramMkrtchyan, Yes it works as the scroll works, You can scroll shift by the box height. It only displays which part is visible no matter what!

Answer (score 1):

```js
// get top positions and references to all blocks
var pos = $(".box").map(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  return {
    el: $this,
    top: $this.offset().top
  };
}).get();

var $result = $("#result-text");

// Set document scrolling event handler
$(document).on("scroll", function() {  
  var visible = [];
  var scrollStart = $(this).scrollTop();
  var scrollEnd = scrollStart+$(window).height();
  var vis=[];
  for (var i=0, l=pos.length; i<l; i++) {
    if (pos[i].top < scrollStart || pos[i].top > scrollEnd) { continue; }
    vis.push(pos[i].el.attr("class"));
  }
  $result.text("");
  $result.text(vis.join(", "));

}).scroll();
```

```css
#result {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.box {
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result">You can see: <span id="result-text"></span></div>
<div class="main">
      <div class="box block1"></div>
      <div class="box block2"></div>
      <div class="box block3"></div>
      <div class="box block4"></div>
      <div class="box block5"></div>
      <div class="box block6"></div>
      <div class="box block7"></div>
      <div class="box block8"></div>
      <div class="box block9"></div>
      <div class="box block10"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time but it write in all div's  You can see me,

Comment: @Aram Mkrtchyan As you can see my solution catches multiple blocks

Comment: ok it also better solution but  what  I want You can see: box block2 it appear when second block visible fully it means that the first bloc when hided fully and second block top will be top in window area, sorry my english :)